# What do we do with community members that write only "Try this code:" answers?

Tags: discussion, answers

I came across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75267848/13629335) and noticed that most of the author's answers are somewhat poorly written, in a "here is your code" manner. I also think I saw others suggesting changing this manner and I do think it is the second time I tried to reach them.

However, in that specific case, it's a valuable question, if edited a little bit and could have lead to a valuable answer. However both sides seems to be consenting on "give me the codz".

Should we even bother then?

Comment: What, exactly, would you want to do? If you think that the post's presentation can be improved, then edit it. Are you just asking what should we do about answers that contain nothing more than code (and no explanation)?

Comment: @CodyGray Somewhat, yes. But I'm more interested if there is a tool or a procedure for the human behind the Q&A. I mean we already have them told what the community standards are, repeatedly I guess. So what's next? Ignoring it?

Comment: There's a downward-facing triangle which you can click to signal that you do not think an answer is clear or helpful.

Comment: "Should we even bother then?" - It depends how apathetic you are feeling today.  :-)

Comment: @CodyGray then they might get offended and do think I'm an "a**h*le, but won't change anything for the future. ^^

Comment: They will most likely be offended anyway :-)

Comment: If they do, that'd be totally ridiculous. And also not your problem. The reality is that "code-only" answers aren't *great*, but they don't break any rules, so if you've already tried gently encouraging a user to add some explanation to their answers (as suggested in [answer]), and that doesn't work, then there really isn't anything else that should or can be done, save for you taking action to indicate to the system and future viewers that the answer isn't all that helpful/useful.

Comment: @StephenC I'll try to avoid this ans save downvote for totally false answers or if they should be comments instead.

Comment: Answers that are not answers should be flagged as "not an answer". You can downvote them if you like, but you should not stop with downvoting them. Of course, answers that are attempts to answer the question should not ever be comments instead, so you shouldn't flag those. You should downvote them if they're not clear or useful. Just like you should downvote answers that you consider to be not useful because they contain no explanation. Eschewing downvoting (or any other content-rating mechanism) out of a fear that someone might be offended is *harmful* to all the future viewers of this site.

Comment: I'm not telling you how you *should* vote.  But a code-only answer typically meets the criteria for a down-vote.  Your choice mate.  But lets be clear: down-voting is the recommended course of action ... if you want to take action.

Comment: Thanks guys, I think I got the idea. Not really attracted by it but I think I got it. In this case my question should probably closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @Thingamabobs Heh, you're definitely not the only one who noticed this particular user. Downvote and move on, anything else seems futile from my experience.

Comment: At least for late answers, the *suspicion* is that most such answers are ***plagiarised code*** (based on similarity with text-only similar late answers). They may have little or no understanding what the code does. But better tools are needed to test if the suspicion is true or not. Often, checking the technical merit of such answers will reveal that they are ***totally bogus*** answers (I have done a few of them where the code didn't look right by initial inspection).

Comment: I agree these answers are not useful for the majority of cases out there. But in this case it is an somewhat "expert technique" sneaking into the mechanic of how the widget itself is built. Another outstanding answer by Bryan and I feel it is understandably that questions arise here. But would also like to mention that it's not that easy to cover all aspects of what that codes does and how it works without writing hundreds of lines of text.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I have the same feeling here.

Comment: @PeterMortensen good point, and seems worth separate discussion. I suspect it's been done on Meta before, though... ?

Comment: A side discussion about plagiarism has been deleted. It doesn't need to be discussed here. The only thing you need to know is that plagiarism is not allowed, and if you find evidence of it, you should raise a flag for moderator attention on the plagiarized answer(s). We will investigate and take the appropriate action. Everyone develops their own heuristics for how to tell if something might be plagiarized. Staff is working on implementing features to better deal with plagiarism, including (but not limited to) a dedicated flag reason. But for now, just use a custom mod flag.